# Inverse relation not set (in KVO handler)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have a very strange problem with inverse relations in Core Data, and I have managed to reduce my problem to a minimal example, starting from a new project in xcode based on the window template with support for Core Data (i.e., there's very little there).

Suppose we have a Core Data model with three entities: Department, Employee, and DepartmentSummary (some sort of entity representing some statistics about the department). For simplicity's sake, we have only one-to-one relations:

```
DepartmentSummary   Department        Employee
---------------------------------------------------------
                    employee  <---->  department
department  <---->  summary
```

This is all there is in the model. In `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` we create an employee and a department and set up KVO:

```
NSManagedObject* employee = 
 [NSEntityDescription 
   insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Employee"
   inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
[employee addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"department" options:0 context:nil];

NSManagedObject* department = 
  [NSEntityDescription 
    insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Department"
    inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
[department setValue:employee forKey:@"employee"];
```

The purpose of the KVO handler is to create a summary for the department as soon as the employee's department is set:

```
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath 
                       ofObject:(id)object 
                         change:(NSDictionary *)change 
                        context:(void *)context 
{
     [self createSummary:object];
}
```

`createSummary` is simple: it creates a new summary object and associates it with the department, and *then checks that the inverse relation from the department to the summary object is also set*:

```
- (void) createSummary:(NSManagedObject*)employee 
{
    NSManagedObject* department = [employee valueForKey:@"department"];
    NSManagedObject* summary = 
     [NSEntityDescription 
       insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"DepartmentSummary"
       inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

    [summary setValue:department forKey:@"department"];

    NSAssert([department valueForKey:@"summary"] == summary, 
             @"Inverse relation not set");
}
```

*This assertion fails.* Indeed, if we print the department and summary objects after the summary's department has been set, we get

```
entity: DepartmentSummary; 
    id: ..DepartmentSummary/..AA14> ; 
  data: { 
    department = "..Department/..AA13>";
  }
```

for the summary, as expected, but

```
entity: Department; 
    id: ..Department/..AA13> ; 
  data: {
    employee = "..Employee/..AA12>";
    summary = nil;
  }
```

for the department (with a `nil` summary). If however we delay the call to `createSummary` so that it doesn't run until the next iteration of the runloop:

```
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath 
                       ofObject:(id)object 
                         change:(NSDictionary *)change 
                        context:(void *)context 
{
     [self performSelector:@selector(createSummary:) 
                withObject:object 
                afterDelay:0];
}
```

then everything works as expected.

Delaying the *assertion* instead does *not* help: the inverse relation really does not get set *in the object graph*, though it does get set in the database (if you were to save the database, and restart the app, now all of a sudden the inverse relation appears).

Is this a bug in Core Data? Is this documented behaviour which I have missed? Am I using Core Data in ways it was not intended?

Note that the KVO handler gets called *while Core Data is (automatically) setting an(other) inverse*: we manually set the department's `employee` field, Core Data automatically sets the employee's `department` field, and that in turn triggers the KVO handler. Perhaps that is just too much for Core Data to handle :) Indeed, when we set

```
[employee setValue:department forKey:@"department"];
```

instead, everything again works as expected.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: What if you set the summary immediately, but delay your *assertion* until the next runloop?

Comment: Excellent question. I'll edit the question to answer it -- basically, delaying the assertion does not help.

Comment: hi, i noticed same, it was working before...

Comment: Hi @edsko, could you please add which version of XCode / iOS SDK this was happening in.  I'm having the same problem in XCode 4.2 / iOS 5.0.

Comment: I first found this problem with iOS 4.3 I think, but it's not fixed in iOS 5. To be honest, I think it is unlikely that it will be fixed at all. It is a pain, but there is nothing for it but to try and workaround it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a classic Core Data problem.  The docs specifically state:

> Since Core Data takes care of the object graph consistency maintenance for you, you only need to change one end of a relationship and all other aspects are managed for you.

However, in practice this is a bald-faced lie, in that it is unreliable.

My answers to your questions is thus:

> Is this a bug in Core Data?

YES.

> Is this documented behaviour which I have missed?

NO.

> Am I using Core Data in ways it was not intended?

NO.

You have already provided the "correct" solution to your problem, the same solution which I use every single time I change relationship values in every single Core Data app I make.  For literally hundreds of cases, the recommended pattern is:

```
[department setValue:employee forKey:@"employee"];
[employee setValue:department forKey:@"department"];
```

ie, set the relationship inverse yourself whenever you change the relationship.

Someone may have more light on this subject, or a more canon form for working around your issue, but in my experience there is no way to guarantee that a relationship is actively available unless it is manually established (as your problem shows).  More importantly, this solution also has two other benefits:

1. It works 100% of the time.
2. It makes the code more readable.

The last point is counter-intuitive.  On the one hand, it seems to complicate the code and make it longer by adding lines to what could be, according to the docs, a short, one-line call.  But in my experience what it does is save a trip by the programmer to the Core Data editor to visually hunt down and confirm model relationships, which is more valuable time-wise.  It's better to be clear and explicit vs having a mental-model of what is supposed to happen when changing a relationship.

I would also suggest adding a simple category to NSManagedObject:

```
@interface NSManagedObject (inverse)

- (void)setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key inverseKey:(NSString *)inverse;

@end

@implementation NSManagedObject (inverse)

- (void)setValue:(id)value forKey:(NSString *)key inverseKey:(NSString *)inverse {
    [self setValue:value forKey:key];
    [value setValue:self forKey:inverse];
}

@end
```

as in:

```
[department setValue:employee forKey:@"employee" inverse:@"department"];
```

there are a few cases to expand upon that category but I would handle, for example, deletion in a different fashion altogether.

**In short:** *handle all your own relationships explicitly every time.*  Core Data is not trustworthy in this regard.

Comment: Hmmm. Interesting. I have found it's more than just when setting relations though. A similar problem happens when deleting a record; the inverse relation might not be set to nil. Do you deal with that manually too? I would be worried that I'll start missing cases. For now, I have made sure that I never change the object graph in a KVO handler; I compute what needs to be done and then schedule it for the next iteration of the runloop. This works, but I have to admit this out-of-order execution makes the code more complicated.

Comment: Yes, when deleting, I always set relationships to nil manually.  In my experience Core Data does reliably schedule objects for deletion according to the rules stated in the docs, so that is not a problem.  To clarify, Core Data in fact does everything it states, only that it does certain operations "when convenient" rather than "right now", as you discover in your code.  If you need a relationship available asap, you should set it yourself.  If you only need it the next time the runloop sets up your UI, let the automated system handle it.

Comment: Also, I would, if I were you, go back to altering relationships in KVO handlers.  This is totally normal.  I would *not* go about inventing my own runtime for Core Data change propagation.  The real insight here is understanding that you need to manage relationships manually, not that you need to "wait" and then handle changes later.

Comment: Actually, no, I disagree with your comment that it will do it eventually. In my example he inverse relation is *never* set in the lifetime of the application. Only when the application is exited and restarted it suddenly appears.

Answer (score 0):

How about saving the ManagedObjectContext right after the insert?

Comment: Neither saving the MOC nor calling processPendingChanges: helps.